# MYSQL, limit for max_user_connections

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am have a trouble with my database, I set up the max_user_connections to 800 and the issue persist, **"User root already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections"** I would like to know if there is a limit for max_user_connections, Can I set 10000 and that is not going to break my database ? 
¿ how can i know the limit ?

If I run `SHOW PROCESSLIST` and Get this, All is right ?
http://prntscr.com/cc8bbv

Comment: How many are used? What does `SHOW PROCESSLIST` show?

Comment: the numbers of users isn't the problem. it's what they're DOING that counts. set the limit to 10,000 if you want. but if you're running 10,000 queries at the same time, you will run into performance problems.

Comment: Who all is accessing the database?  Reason I ask is because if there are lots of different users needing access then this is a valid problem.  But if not, and you are the only one needing access, then the problem is that you aren't closing your previous connections.

Comment: Mark B. Is correct in his comment!
Check this link out for more info: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html

Comment: Not enough info,do you close the connection in your application after use?

Answer (score 1):

To see what is the max connnections for a user use the vairable in information_schema for your mysql database to see global configuration for this.

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "max_user_connections";
```

If it is zero, then it is no limit otherwise the limit is set to the one as response.

If you want to check for particular user, use this

```
SELECT max_user_connections FROM mysql.user WHERE user='db_user' AND host='localhost';
```

Now for your question what is the effect on increasing this, As per

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/update-max-connections-mysql/

> Note that increasing the number of connections that can be made will
>   increase the potential amount of RAM required for MySQL to run.
>   Increase the max_connections setting with caution!

So here max_connections is total number of connections allowed from all users.

Also i would suggest to use connection pool so that the size of pool is fixed and it will be from that only and is not growing. Also make sure it is returned back to pool once the work is done.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Do you know how can I calculate the max_connections based on the RAM ?

Answer (score 0):

**Too many active connections**

The problem you are having is because you are not closing previous connections you have used to access the database.  (And its also likely that you are running many separate queries that could all be compressed into a single query)

From looking at your error message, "User root" has more than the max available connections.  There aren't 800 different people accessing the database, you are accessing the database 800 different times and not cleaning up afterwards.

Comment: Is a Good option, I will check the CMS connections.